# Nginx + PHP maximum output limit

Tags: php, nginx

I have php 5.5 (fpm) and nginx 1.10 installed (gzip configured to 1). Running on ubuntu.

When I am "echoing" a large output, it stops abruptly at around 520 kb.

But same program when I run on php-cli, it has no problem "echoing" onto the terminal.

How to fix this?

EDIT: There is nothing wrong with my program. Even a simple long enough for loop spurting out echo "hello world" gets stopped at specific byte limit.

I am not sure if this issue is caused from nginx side or php side.

Comment: Please check your access and error logs. They may contain useful information.

Comment: No clue was found in both logs. Sorry I forgot to post it along my question but I did check one more time after you commented.